# iPhone Development: What kind of data structures are available?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, data-structures

This is a very newbie questions, but does the iPhone API provide any data structures to work with (i.e. linked list, hash map, etc.)?

Comment: Note that `NS(Mutable)Array` doesn't necessarily store object pointers in a C-style array. It dynamically changes its internal representation between a C-style array, a linked list, and any other number of structures based on how you use it.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use **any** data structure implemented on C or C++ with iPhone SDK.

For example, I use [standard library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp) a lot.

Besides that, you can also use Cocoa's complex data structures available like:

1. NSArray
2. NSDictionary (hash)
3. NSSet (set)

You can have a companion document on them [here](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/collections/index.html).

Comment: Technicality: Objective-C itself does not provide these classes—they are a part of *Cocoa*. Objective-C is just the language that is used. Not a huge deal, but it's a good idea to get into the habit of referring to these things correctly. ;)

Comment: Agree. Going to change my answer to reflect what you are saying. Thanks!

Answer (score 12):

Cocoa (a framework available both on Mac and iOS) implements [several common collection types](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Collections/), including `NSArray`, `NSDictionary`, and `NSSet`, as well as their mutable variants. (Leopard also introduced `NSPointerArray`, `NSHashMap`, and `NSHashTable`, an array/dictionary/set with additional options (like using weak references) that make them a rather convenient to use in a garbage collected environment. However, these classes aren't currently available on iPhone, and would make little sense at the moment, since iOS doesn't support garbage collection.) These classes are extremely fast, and are suitable for general-purpose use in any Cocoa application.

Beyond these provided structures, you have several choices: (1) create more complex structures using these as building blocks, (2) leverage existing third-party code, or (3) build your own data structures from scratch.

One option is [CHDataStructures.framework](http://cocoaheads.byu.edu/code/CHDataStructures), an open-source Objective-C framework which I maintain. It implements several other common data structures, such as stack/queue/deque, linked lists, sorted sets, and more. These structures adopt [NSCoding](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSCoding_Protocol) and [NSCopying](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSCopying_Protocol) (plus [NSFastEnumeration](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSFastEnumeration_protocol/) on 10.5+), so they work seamlessly with native Objective-C code. The project allows you to build a static library for use on iPhone as well. Since this framework is open source, you can even include only the relevant code directly in your project if needed.

While you **can** use C++ and STL structures, I have found that mixing Objective-C and C++ tends to be much more confusing and lead to in vexing bugs, especially for novices. This isn't a bash against C++, just a "when in Rome" principle. When using C++, STL is of course the preferred approach. If you're already mixing in C++, you're probably comfortable enough with it that STL might be a good choice; even so, I find that using native Cocoa collections produces more self-evident, readable code.

Comment: Sure would be nice if those who feel the need to downvote would leave some feedback as to *why* they feel a response is "not helpful"...

Comment: I do not believe that NSHashMap, NSHashTable or NSPointerArray are available on the iphone.

Comment: Carl is right, and since I didn't find this info anywhere else on SO, I want to state it clearly: NSHashMap, NSHashTable and NSPointerArray are not available in the iPhone SDK. See this question for a description of how to use NSValue to box pointers:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/393662/does-using-lists-of-structs-make-sense-in-cocoa

Comment: Ugh... that was the wrong link but... The point is: use NSValue to wrap pointers and put them in Cocoa collections.

Comment: I have a hard time finding ``NSHashMap``; isn't it supposed to be ``NSMaptable``?

Answer (score -4):

The Objective-C language does not provide any inherent data structures like Linked Lists, etc. However, as it is based off of the C/C++ codebase, anything that can be implemented in C or C++ can be done directly in Objective-C, including Linked Lists and other data structures.

Comment: Objective-C is in no way "based off of the C++ codebase." C, yes, but anything C++ you have to go out of your way to use (and be somewhat masochistic)