# How do I Sort Collections in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, algorithm, sorting

I have an integer array in my Objective-C program.  I'd like to sort it (ascending or descending, doesn't matter).  In C++ I'd use the sort algorithm in the STL Algorithm library.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The "Cocoa" way is to create NSNumber objects, add them to an NSArray, and use the `sortUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)` method (or one of the other NSArray sort methods).

If you want to create a C array of primitive NSInteger (int) values, you can use the built-in [`qsort(…)`](http://www.cppreference.com/wiki/c/other/qsort) function of C.

Answer (score 2):

Even though this question has already been answered, I would like to add that you can also use STL collections with Objective-C++ and iPhone programming. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/766581/iphone-development-what-kind-of-data-structures-are-available/) is a link to a previous discussion on the topic.